# Security firewall still asking for logged in access

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a controller where I check, trough AJAX call from view and executing the logic on the controller, if some values exists or not at database. Because I'm using FOSUserBundle I have added this line to the controller: `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security` then in each method of the controller I added this annotation:

```
/**
 * @Route("/check/{value}", name="check")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Security("has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')")
 */
public function checkExistsAction($value = null) {
   // some logic goes here  
}
```

That doesn't work since I get login form as result and not the JSON I made inside the function, I already try by adding directly the route to  the `security.yml` as follow:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }    
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But that doesn't work either. Any advice? What I'm doing wrong here?

PS: I notice something curious on Netbeans IDE (maybe is one of that crazy things of NB) and is that Security isn't recognized as a annotation, see picture below and notice the Security line with some warning:

[image]

**Some others unsuccessful tests**

First test: Since I'm using `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` also I have added this line to my controller: `use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;` then I made some changes at my code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/check/{value}", name="check")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
 */
public function checkExistsAction($value = null) {
   // some logic goes here  
}
```

Result: Didn't work.

Second test: I disable the security at `access_control` as follow:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Then clear the cache.

Result: Didn't work.

I don't know what else to do in order to get this working. This is the `firewall` definition at `security.yml` file:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
             path: fos_user_security_logout
             target: /
             invalidate_session: false
        anonymous: ~
```

Any advice or ideas? I'm out of them and getting crazy with this.

**Correction**

With second test, after changes `framework-extra-bundle` from stable to dev things start working but this is not right since I'm leaving my application without any security so I need another path or solution

Comment: Are you importing the security annotation?

Comment: @echochamber what you mean with security annotation? This `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security`?

Comment: yes, thats the correct one. My reply was too long for a comment so I made it an answer, discuss in the comments on the answer.

Comment: also I'd recommend checking out PhpStorm and the Symfony2 plugin for it. Its made and supported by the symfony2 team and it makes your IDE have a bunch of extra functionality specific to symfony to (autocompleting routes, views, services, and performing static analysis on your service definitions as well).

Comment: @echochamber thx for the suggestion I used before but I messed up in somewhere with remote project and I drop out the IDE in favor of Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are properly authenticated? Make sure your http request is sending the cookie: 'PHPSESSID=svhag4u4fkj0em722eo5cd1pm4' header. (shouldn't have exactly that value). If thats true, then make sure that the user is actually being authenticated. You can do this by removing your security annotation and checking what the value of

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
//This only works in the controller
```

using var_dump or by debugging it. If that value is null that means your user provider isn't actually loading the user, and you either aren't authenticated or have a configuration issue.

Edit:

I just noticed the issue.

IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY will return true if the user is not logged in. So if you have logged in this will actually prevent you from viewing any of those routes.

Comment: That's the idea I need access to that function without need to login since they are part of the register flow, what's wrong then?

Comment: @ReynierPM are you accessing your app through app_dev.php or app.php? Its possible the security values are still cached, and so the annotations aren't being checking? Try clearing the cache? Also its possible this line `- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }` is getting parsed before your annotation. Symfony uses the first found matching pattern for checking if a user has access. (Same way it does routing).

Comment: I'm accessing trough `app_dev.php` by now since I'm still on dev stage, I tried by cleaning cache and problem still, right now I remove all annotation from the file and leave only the entries on `access_control` and it works but is not the idea since I'll need to add then any route I want to get out of firewall

Comment: I've added some extra information to main post, please take a look and try to give me some ideas since I'm out of them

Comment: @ReynierPM which version `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` do you have?, [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) says that you must have at least sf 2.4 and `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle 3.0` to make `@Security` annotation works

Comment: @tttony I'm running Symfony 2.5.3 and if I'm right I have `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle 3.0` as this line said in my `composer.json` : `"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0"`

Comment: @ReynierPM this is the first time that you test Security annotations or it worked fine before?

Comment: @tttony yes, I updated the `composer.json` by changing this `"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"` and updating the bundles which cause remove 3.0.1 and install the current dev branch but still not working I don't know what else to do

Comment: @ReynierPM test it in another action, also you can test it in the controller itself

Comment: @tttony I've tested in two different action and two different controllers none works, how do I test in action if I can not enter to that action?